# scrolling to top of the page after loading a div at a click

Tags: ajax

I am very new to jquery, ajax and stuck at this one point -

I have a div that gets loaded when a href "link1" is clicked. 
I want the page to scroll to the top / use animate to go to a specific div at the click.

This is my code -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href="#link1"]').click(function(){
    $("#position").load("url/test.php #replace");
        return false;}).scrollTop();
});
```

Comment: use scroll top() after .load()

Comment: accept as answer if it satisfies ur requirement

Answer (score 1):

[Check The Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UJL3w/4/)

***In this Demo when you click the divs in green/blue color data from external link will be loaded and with specific Id ="specialContent" and after that it scrolls to the div where its loaded***

### HTML

```
<div id="Container">
<div id="ChildTOP">
    
</div>     
<div id="ChildLEFT">
    
</div>     
    
</div>
```

### Jquery

```
$('#ChildLEFT').on('click',function(){
var lenContainer = $('#Container').offset();
    var lenDiv = $('#ChildLEFT').offset();

$('#ChildLEFT').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/webdevem/JfcJp/show/ #specialContent');
$(window).scrollTop(lenDiv.top);
    
});


$('#ChildTOP').on('click',function(){
var lenContainer = $('#Container').offset();
    var lenDiv = $('#ChildTOP').offset();

$('#ChildTOP').load('http://fiddle.jshell.net/webdevem/JfcJp/show/ #specialContent');
$(window).scrollTop(lenDiv.top);
    
});
```

### CSS

```
#Container{
    
    height:1000px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:orange;
}
#ChildTOP{
    
    height:480px;
    width:97%;
    background-color:#1C8B98;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    
}
#ChildLEFT{
    
    height:480px;
    width:97%;
    background-color:#1C8B98;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    
}
```